# batch recursive move files of extension to folder named with that extension

Tags: bash, recursion, move

I have files of type mp3 and flac. Lets say my basic directory structure is

```
/music/artist/album
```

I have (already) made

```
/music/artist/album/flac/
/music/artist/album/mp3/
```

with a recursive batch operation.

I want to loop through all of `/music/` and do the following:

1. If `/music/artist/album/`  has mp3s, move them to `/music/artist/album/mp3/`.
2. If `/music/artist/album/` has flacs, move them to `/music/artist/album/flac/`.

Some folders have mp3 and flac. Looking for either script file or command line solutions

Comment: What OS is this for? The tags bash and batch-file are different

Comment: sorry, for the mistake on the tags.  Files are on an external hard drive and I intend to do the operation in Ubuntu

Comment: I have received a solution that I needed.  thank you all again for your help and suggestions.  I have learned a lot already!   Best regards!

Comment: Then please go ahead and accept the answer, it'll help people find it faster in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find /music/ -name '*.mp3'  -execdir mv {} mp3/  \;
find /music/ -name '*.flac' -execdir mv {} flac/ \;
```

`-execdir` runs the specified command in the directory of the current file. This lets you use `mp3/` and `flac/` directories relative to the current artist/album.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have one way to do it :

```
find /music  -type f -name "*.mp3" | xargs mv $1 /music/artist/album/mp3/
find /music  -type f -name "*.flac" | xargs mv $1 /music/artist/album/flac/
```

Hope it works for you.

Greetings!

Comment: thank you for the reply. unfortunately maybe my original comment was not clear enough.  "artist" and "album"  are actually thousands of subfolders - like  Rolling Stones, Beethoven, etc.   so I don't think doing it the way you provided wouldn't quite work unless I passed them in as variables.

Answer (score 0):

Change the current directory to where your music files are, then move mp3s to the mp3 folder and flacs to the flac folder.

```
cd /music/artist/album/
mv *.mp3 mp3/
mv *.flac flac/
```

Comment: thank you for the comment, but I know how to do that and it would require over 1000 iterations to do manually.   that's why I asked for a recursive batch command to work in /music/